# .NET Core 5 - Docker Compose manually from VSCode does not run the application

Tags: asp.net, docker, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, docker-compose

I am new to docker and I need a bit of help.

I had a .Net Core Solutions that contains 2 web projects one of them is the web application and the other one is the web API. I have created a default docker compose.yml to these 2 projects from Visual Studio 2019. When I tried to run this from Visual Studio 2019, it works as usual.

However, when I go to the solution folder from my VSCode and run docker-compose on the terminal, the containers are running for these 2 projects but when I tried to access the webpage by going to localhost:{port number} it gives me the error from the image below

[image]

I did not change any docker-compose.yml and the Dockerfile but it still does not run as intended.

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  innovent.webservices:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}innoventwebservices
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Innovent.WebServices/Dockerfile
  innovent.web:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}innoventweb
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Innovent.Web/Dockerfile
```

^docker-compose.yml^

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Innovent.Web/Innovent.Web.csproj", "Innovent.Web/"]
COPY ["Innovent.Model/Innovent.Model.csproj", "Innovent.Model/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Innovent.Web/Innovent.Web.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Innovent.Web"
RUN dotnet build "Innovent.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Innovent.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Innovent.Web.dll"]
```

^Dockerfile^

Could someone give me a guide on this?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an SSL error because your container doesn't have an HTTPS certificate.

You will need:

1. Create an HTTPS certificate with `dotnet dev-certs` command
2. Map the certificate to your container

your docker-compose needs to have something like:

```yaml
      environment:
         - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
         - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=MYPWD
         - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
      volumes:
         - ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro
```

This [post](https://tomssl.com/how-to-run-asp-net-core-3-1-over-https-in-docker-using-linux-containers/) has a really nice example

Comment: Thanks @LukasBazetto for the help. I've created a HTTPS certificate but I could not map it to my container.

Comment: What I did is run 
- ```dotnet dev-certs https --trust -ep .aspnet\https\aspnetapp.pfx -p MYPASSWORD``` so now the pfx file is located on ```C:\Users\aswin\.aspnet\https\aspnetapp.pfx```. 
- Then I added this line to docker-compose.override.yml 
```- ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=MYPASSWORD
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=C:\Users\aswin\.aspnet\https\aspnetapp.pfx```. 

But it throws an error ```Interop.Crypto.OpenSslCryptographicException: 'error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file' ```. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: you are missing the volume. I updated my answer